# Set charset when processing xml using Dispatch Databinder 0.10

Tags: scala, scalatra, scala-dispatch

I'm wrapping an upstream API with a Scalatra application and using Dispatch to make async requests. However, I'm having trouble turning the upstream XML into `xml.Elems` using Dispatch's built-in XML processing support.

I'm trying to do something fairly similar to what's in the Dispatch docs, namely retrieve the upstream XML and do some reprocessing. The functions in question look something like:

```
  def facilitiesSvc = {
    val myhost = host("upstream.api.co.uk") / "organisations" / "foo" / "123" / "bar" / "core.xml"
    myhost.addQueryParameter("apikey", "123456")
    myhost
  }

  def facilitiesXml: Future[Either[String, xml.Elem]] = {
    val res: Future[Either[Throwable, xml.Elem]] = Http((facilitiesSvc) OK as.xml.Elem).either
    for(exc <- res.left)
      yield "Can't connect to facilities service: \n" +
        exc.getMessage
  }
```

This results in:

```
Left(Can't connect to facilities service: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.)
```

The upstream API isn't sending back a charset, and when retrieving it, Dispatch is showing it with a Byte Order Mark before the XML begins: `ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

I can see that earlier versions of Dispatch solved this problem [in the following way](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dispatch-scala/0DMCsmLYCiY/mClejgg-QaAJ):

```
new Http apply(url(uri.toString).copy(defaultCharset = "iso-8859-1") as_str)
```

However I can't currently see a way to make this work with Dispatch 0.10. Does anybody have any tips for setting the charset on this response, so I can parse what's returned?

Comment: The same problem here